# como poder solucionar Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br /> <b>"... is not valid JSON

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7

estoy con mis compañeros solucionando este problema con json, entiendo que mi error esta en que el json no esta valido, pero aun no descubrimos el porque, alguien me podria ayudar porfavor para saber que debo agregar o que debo quitar, mi conexion a phpmyadmin con xampp esta bien, es un sistema PARA UNA EMPRESA DE CALLCENTER los cuales buscaran muchos telefonos y dni por medio de cargar un archivo masivo para consultar dni, y poder cargar masivamente un excel, agradezco ayuda porfavor, saludos y cariños a todos!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://localhost/rut/resultados.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" id="rut" name="rut" value=""><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="obtenerResultados()">Buscar</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="clearResults()">Limpiar Resultados</button>
  </form>

  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rut</th>
        <th>Teléfono</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resultados"></tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>



<?php
include 'conexion.php';
error_reporting(0);

$dbname="sistema";
$dbuser="root";
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbpass="";

$conexion=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

// llamada a base datos

$sql = 'SELEC * from ruts';

$where = explode(',', $_POST['rut']);
$listRuts = '';

foreach ($where as $key => $rt) {
  $sep = ',';
  $listRuts .= "'" . $rt . "'";
  if ($key < (sizeof($where) - 1)) {
    $listRuts .= $sep;
  }
}

if (!empty($where)) {
  /* where rut in ('222','333','444'); */
  $sql .= ' where rut IN (' . $listRuts . ')';
}

$resultados=$conexion->query($sql);
echo json_encode($resultados->fetch_assoc());
$resultados->free_result();
$conexion->close();
?>




function clearResults() {
  let rutHTML = document.getElementById('rut');
  let formHTML = document.getElementById('resultados');
  rutHTML.value = ''
  formHTML.innerHTML = ''
}

function obtenerResultados() {

  clearResults()

  const formDomObject = document.querySelector('form'); // obtengo el dom del formulario HTML
  const formData = new FormData(formDomObject) // implemento la clase FormData

  fetch('http://localhost/rut/conexion.php', { // hago la llamada a la url con la lógica de negocio
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
    .then(res => res.json()) // transforma el resultado a JSON
    .then(data => {

      console.log(data) // presento la data hacia el HTML

      let formHTML = document.getElementById('resultados');
      Object.values(data).forEach(row => {
        console.log(row)
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');

        let tdRut = document.createElement('td');
        tdRut.innerHTML = row.rut

        let tdFono = document.createElement('td');
        tdFono.innerHTML = row.telefono

        tr.appendChild(tdRut)
        tr.appendChild(tdFono)

        formHTML.appendChild(tr)


      })

    })

}
```

Comment: Hola Salvador, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Pueden ser muchas cosas, pero normalmente pasa que cuando hay un error o warning PHP envía un mensaje en formato HTML, este mensaje se acopla al JSON generando un JSON no valido. En el navegador presiona F12, te vas a la pestaña `Red` y ejecuta el asunto, en la lista aparecerá un nuevo elemento, verifica en la pestaña `Salida` lo que te está retornando el servidor